# StackOverFlow error whith ModelMapper converting Set to Set

Tags: java, list, set, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper to convert my User and Address objects to UserDto and AddressDto. Here are my pojos:

```
public class User {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  <...>
  private Set<Address> addresses;
}

public class Address {
  private Long id;
  private User user;
  <...>
  private String country;
}

public class UserDto {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  <...>
  private Set<AddressDto> addresses;
}

public class AddressDto {
  private Long id;
  private Long userId;
  <...>
  private String country;
}
```

And here is my ModelMapper config:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModelMapperConfig {
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

@PostConstruct
public void addPropertyMaps() {
    PropertyMap<Address, AddressDto> addressDtoPropertyMap = new PropertyMap<>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map(source.getId()).setId(null);
            map(source.getUser().getId()).setUserId(null);
            map(source.getCountry()).setCountry(null);
            map(source.getRegion()).setRegion(null);
            map(source.getCity()).setCity(null);
            map(source.getFirstAddressLine()).setFirstAddressLine(null);
            map(source.getSecondAddressLine()).setSecondAddressLine(null);
            map(source.getZipCode()).setZipCode(null);
        }
    };
    modelMapper.addMappings(addressDtoPropertyMap);

    PropertyMap<User, UserDto> userDtoPropertyMap = new PropertyMap<>() {
        final Converter<Set<Address>, Set<AddressDto>> converter = new Converter<>() {
            @Override
            public Set<AddressDto> convert(MappingContext<Set<Address>, Set<AddressDto>> context) {
                return context.getSource()
                        .stream()
                        .map(address -> modelMapper.map(address, AddressDto.class))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map(source.getId()).setId(null);
            map(source.getFirstName()).setFirstName(null);
            map(source.getLastName()).setLastName(null);
            map(source.getMiddleName()).setMiddleName(null);
            using(converter).map(source.getAddresses()).setAddresses(null);
            map(source.getEmail()).setEmail(null);
            map(source.getPassword()).setPassword(null);
            map(source.getPhone()).setPhone(null);
        }
    };
    modelMapper.addMappings(userDtoPropertyMap);
}
```

}

When I'm trying to map User to UserDto I get stackOverFlowError with huge trace. But if I change Set in User to List my code works exactly as I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Stacktrace (part of it):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:552) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:406) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityUsingInterceptor(SessionImpl.java:566) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.loadFromSessionCache(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:517) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1051) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeGet(EntityType.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:866) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.readFrom(PersistentSet.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4685) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at apivanushkin.ollivander.userservice.model.User.hashCode(User.java:109) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4685) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at apivanushkin.ollivander.userservice.model.Address.hashCode(Address.java:122) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Comment: StackOverflow usually means you are continuously creating objects up until the moment all of your systems resources are used, and you create just the one more.

Comment: for each User, you have a Set of Addresses, for each of those Addresses, you have a User, for that User, you once again have a Set of Addresses, for each of which, again, you have a User, ... See the problem? The problem is in your design

Comment: But why than changing Set type to List in User.class solves problem?